# GUI Program For Drawing 2D Pixel Arrays

Tags: arduino

Does anyone know of any? I'd like to use this for drawing on my 2D LED arduino project (rather than manually generating the arrays).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [PeggyDraw 2](http://www.evilmadscientist.com/2011/peggydraw-2/) for an open source example done in Processing which uses a GUI to generate LED animation array data.